# revers timestamp in linux with specific format

Tags: linux, date, timestamp

i am in Linux system i have timestamp in this mode 1633986034 i want  convert in this format `2022/04/01 22:10:05`  how  is possible do that. ??
I try in this mode but not work correct  `date -d @1633986034`
thanks at all

Comment: Try https://www.epochconverter.com/
1633986034 is not 2022

Answer (score 0):

Try `date -d '@1633986034' +'%Y/%m/%d %T'`.
For more information about formating dates read the [date man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the date format you want to get, for example :

```
date -d "@1633986034" +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
--> 2021/10/11 23:00:34
```